# SQL Select Statement against attributes indexed UNIQUE

Tags: sql, select

Have a table with three columns: col1 being primary INT, col2 & col 3 being UNIQUE and INT.

I need to select those rows in which col1, col2 and col3 are equal to const1, and col2 and

col3 are not equal to zero.

Is the following query correct?

**NOTE**: Have used meaningful names for attributes, and the values given here for

illistrative purposes only.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 = const OR col2 = const OR col3 = const AND (coll2 <> 0 AND col3 <> 0);
```

const can be any INT values

Comment: You say "not equal" in the text but your query appears to be comparing with `=`?

Comment: @OlegDok: Definitely not. Even if it was, I have atleast tried only to find the logic incorrect, rather than just copy the question from my notes.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Oops. What I basically need to do is to select those rows that match a particular const values, and such that the const value, and / or attribute values is / are not zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused but based on this:

```
What I basically need to do is to select those rows that match a particular const values, and such that the const value, and / or attribute values is / are not zero
```

I think what you want is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE 
(col1 = const1 or col2 = const1 or col3 = const1) and (col1 != 0 and col2 != 0 and col3 are !=0)
```

I understood that at least one of the columns need to match the const but it cant be zero

Comment: Yes. Right. One or more column should match const, but shouldn't be zero.

Comment: Why does the answer is right since it is opposite to question? Cols are have **not** to be equal to const according to the question

Comment: @diego Ok, I edited the question according to author's comment

Answer (score 5):

No, query is not correct. Here is the correct one:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE 
    const1 IN (col1, col2, col3) 
AND 0 NOT IN (col2, col3)
```

**Update:**

Your query finds all the rows where col2 <> 0 and col3 <> 0 and appends all the rows where one or more columns is equal to const

Comment: Thanks. Do you mind telling me what the query that I gave basically does...?